# Why if $G_n$ is a subgroup of G then G is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found this exercise, that says:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $G_n=\{g^n : g\in G\}$. Under what hypothesis about $G$ can we show that $G_n$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Apparently the answer is that G has to be abelian, but I don't see why.

Reference: Fraleigh p. 59 Question 5.56 in A First Course in Abstract Algebra

Comment: I think you mean $<g>=\{g^n\ |\ n\in \Bbb Z \}$?

Comment: The original problem used: $G_n=\{g^n:g\in G\}$

Comment: @AnaGalois Can you please type in the non translated version? I feel like you might have mistranslated.

Comment: Someone might need to check my facts on this, but I'm pretty sure $<g>$ exclusively denotes what I said in my above comment.

Comment: I think i made a mistake, i thought Gn was the same as <g>.
@GitGud sorry i don't understand, i'm pretty new in this site :P

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, then $G_n$ is a subgroup. In a non-abelian group, $G_n$ may or may not be a subgroup.

Comment: @AnaGalois You translated a problem into english from your native language, right? Can you please edit the question and add the original problem in your native language?

Comment: I change the problem. @GitGud Ok, i got this problem from a book in english, "A first course in Abstract Algebra" by Fraleigh (secc. 1.3, pp 70) that's exactly what it says

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $G$ is abelian, then $G_n = \{ g^n : g \in G \}$ is closed under multiplication since $g^n \cdot h^n = (gh)^n$ by repeatedly commuting $g$s past $h$s. $G_n$ is always closed under inversion.

If $G$ is a group with the property that $g^n h^n = (gh)^n$ for all $g,h \in G$, then $G$ is called $n$-abelian. 2-abelian groups are abelian, but 3-abelian groups need not be abelian.

Furthermore, $G_n$ may happen to be a subgroup even if $g^n h^n \neq (gh)^n$ as all that is required is that $g^n h^n = k^n$ for some $k \in G$. For instance if $G$ is dihedral of order 8, then $G_3 = G$ is a subgroup, but $G$ is not 3-abelian.

Answer (score 3):

$\langle g \rangle$ is always a subgroup; it contains the identity element ($g^0 = e$) and is clearly closed under multiplication ($g^n g^m = g^{n+m}$). There are no conditions required on the group $G$.

Note that $\langle g \rangle$ is the standard notation for $\{g^n : n \in \Bbb Z\}$. Now if
$$G_n = \{g^n : g \in G\}$$
where $n$ is fixed, then $G_n$ is a subgroup if $G$ is abelian, but if $G$ is nonabelian it depends. For example, if $G = D_n$ is a dihedral group, then $G_2$ is a subgroup. On the other hand, if $G = A_4$, the alternating group on $4$ letters, then $G_2$ is not a subgroup.